# Writing a custom insert function for std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I was writing the insert function for std::vector for my personal project.

Vector layout before insert:

```
position : 0 1 2 3 4
Value    : a b c e f
```

**Assuming there is enough capacity**, I want to insert 'd' at position 3.

Vector layout after insert:

```
position : 0 1 2 3 4 5
Value    : a b c d e f
```

I wrote a function to shift the values to the right after the given insert position (in the example it is 3) and then I assign the given value at the requested insert position.

The function I wrote to shift_right is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void vector<T>::shift_right(typename vector<T>::iterator given_pos) {
    for (auto iter = end() - 1; iter != given_pos - 1; iter--) {
        *(iter + 1) = *iter;
    }
}
```

Is there a **std::algorithm**, or variation of it that can help **me get rid of my raw loop** in the shift_right function?

Comment: I think maybe [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) can help here? Or maybe [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) and [std::move_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward).

Comment: You should first make sure that there is enough capacity for the vector.

Comment: My implementation is working. I already made sure that there is enough capacity (Also mentioned in the post).

Comment: @Galik I did look into rotate. Couldn't wrap my head around implementing that.

Comment: you may want to use a namespace, e.g. `my::vector` to make it obvious that you are writing your own class

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::move_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward):

> ```
> template< class BidirIt1, class BidirIt2 ><br>
> BidirIt2 move_backward( BidirIt1 first, BidirIt1 last, BidirIt2 d_last );
> ```
>
> Moves the elements from the range `[first, last)`, to another range ending at `d_last`. The elements are moved in reverse order (the last element is moved first), but their relative order is preserved.

So your code might look like this (not tested):

```
template <typename T>
void vector<T>::shift_right(typename vector<T>::iterator given_pos) {
    std::move_backward(given_pos, end()-2, end()-1);
}
```

This assumes that the capacity has already been increased if necessary and that `end()` returns the *new* end iterator (i.e. one past the last element after the new space was inserted). Change to `std::move_backward(given_pos, end()-1, end());` if that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator 
shift_right( std::vector<T> &v, typename std::vector<T>::size_type pos )
{
    v.resize( v.size() + 1 );

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator result = std::end( v );

    if ( pos < v.size() )
    {
        result = std::copy_backward( std::next( std::begin( v ), pos ), 
                                     std::prev( std::end( v  )),
                                     std::end( v ) );
    }

    return std::prev( result ); 
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    auto it = shift_right( v, v.size( ) );

    *it = 2;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    it = shift_right( v, v.size() );
    *it = 3;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    it = shift_right( v, 0 );
    *it = 0;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    it = shift_right( v, 1 );
    *it = 1;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 
2 3 
0 2 3 
0 1 2 3
```

Pay attention to that it is better to use `std::copy_backward` instead of `std::move_backward` because in the first case the state of all elements of the vector will be consistent similarly to elements of an array of fundamental types after shifting them.

If to use `std::move_backward` then the corresponding function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator 
shift_right( std::vector<T> &v, typename std::vector<T>::size_type pos )
{
    v.resize( v.size() + 1 );

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator result = std::end( v );

    if ( pos < v.size() )
    {
        result = std::move_backward( std::next( std::begin( v ), pos ), 
                                     std::prev( std::end( v  )),
                                     std::end( v ) );
    }

    result = std::prev( result );
    *result = T();

    return result; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    auto it = shift_right( v, 2 );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    *it = 3;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 4 5 6 
1 2 0 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: `v.resize( v.size() + 1 )`. That is.

Answer (score 0):

I would first define a convenience function template, `right_shift_by_one()`,  that shifts the elements to the right by one position in the ***valid*** iterator range [`first`, `last`):

```
template<typename BidirIt>
void right_shift_by_one(BidirIt first, BidirIt last) {
   std::move_backward(first, std::prev(last), last);
}
```

Then, your custom vector's member function, `shift_right()`, which eventually calls the convenience function defined above:

```
template<typename T>
auto shift_right(typename vector<T>::iterator pos) {
   auto dist = std::distance(begin(), pos);

   // this only compiles if T is default constructible
   resize(size()+1);

   // resize() may have invalidated the pos iterator due to vector's reallocation
   // recompute it
   pos = begin() + dist;

   right_shift_by_one(pos, end());
   return pos;
}
```

This member function returns an iterator pointing to the element corresponding to the new space created by right shifting. This works even if the vector doesn't have enough capacity because the invalidation of iterators on reallocation has been taken into account. You have to implement `resize()` in your custom vector implementation, though.

Use:

```
auto it = shift_right(vec.begin() + 2);
*it = 'c';
```